# Printing plain text in an aligned grid format

Tags: java, string, algorithm, text, javafx

i would love to know the recipe to printing out text in a grid Layout format or table Layout format, where the input text are vertically aligned in a column|row type layout -(it could be any language, i am interested in the recipe)

for example suppose i have an array of Strings representing my row

```
String[] s = new String[]{"Adele","Taylor","Katty","Beyonce","Mariah"};
String[] s1 = new String[]{"Java","Android","Ruby","Pascal","Python"};
String[] s2 = new String[]{"Ronaldo","Ibrahimovic","Tevez","Rooney","Ronaldhino"};
String[] s3 = new String[]{"Stackoverflow","Facebook","Twitter","Amazon","Scrybasms"};
```

and i want to print this to a console/text file/ etc in table looking format like this

```
Adele                  Taylor               Katty                        Beyonce                                Mariah 
Java                   Android              Ruby                         Pascal                                 Python 
Ronaldo                Ibrahimovic          Tevez                        Rooney                                 Ronaldhino
Stackoverflow          Facebook             Twitter                      Amazon                                 Scrybasms
```

but you can see they are not correctly aligned; On a gui app this is how it looks
[image]

and on my eclipse

[image]

they all have different alignments, and i do not know why hence i want a general better way of achieving what i want. thanks

**EDIT**

Thank you all, both commenters and answerers i have solved it with the most word occurrence "MonoSpace". :)

[image]

Comment: This is impossible since you don't know which font will be used to display the text (for text files it would depend on the program displaying it, maybe even the program settings - you already demonstrated in the question). In the case a gui library you could be able to set the font or determine the font and use it's properties to measure text widths (with no guaranty that exact alignment is even possible with a given font [except for monospaced fonts].)

Comment: I think using a `Table` is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: @fabian i am now trying it will let you know whats up, thank you, and if i can get it to work- will thank you again; hope your first three words wasn't meant to mean the way they sound :)

Comment: can you give me a logic to use table and make it look and function like a text display? will be glad im a day way from bounty though @PhamTrung

Comment: There are few options to pad text in Java. You can use Strings.format, or Apache StringUtils or Guava libraries. In all of them the text used for output should be monospaced.

Comment: thanks @UlukBiy i maintained my code and used monospace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `eclipse`, it's mono-space font, like here:

```
aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
eeee ffff gggg hhhh
iiii jjjj kkkk llll
```

In your application, it's not mono-space font, like here:

> aaaa bbbb cccc
>
> dddd eeee ffff
>
> gggg hhhh iiii
>
> jjjj kkkk llll

So now you see why it is aligned correctly in your eclipse but failed in your application.

Comment: @Elltz You are welcome :) If there is no more problem here, it would be better to set one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Use mono-spaced font and align the text with spaces.

Or use separate UI elements(text boxes) for each column of text. Each column will then locally align its text independent of the others.

Comment: hmm, this will be costly sir, don't you think? also if i am to treat the whole node as a text display then it needs to function like one ? for example like finding stuff on my text display etc etc. any tips sir?

Comment: If you want to extend functions like search you could define your own text element that is composed of a few text boxes (the columns) then forward the functions of interest to each of the internal text boxes. You can also use this custom element to manage the text (i.e. when you insert an element you don't just push down the text in that column, but rearrange all of them to look like you wish).

Comment: It's always more costly to roll your own custom elements. But if the default ones don't do what you want you can either accept it or implement your own (or hire somebody to do it for you).

Comment: thanks Sir. was very helpful - i mean the monspace, the rest well thanks anyways sir

Answer (score 1):

Most languages have a pad function, which takes a string and pads it out with spaces until it is the desired length. If they don't support this, they at least support C string formatting, which allows things like "%1$10s" (which will put up to 10 spaces on the front of the string).

This is a much easier way to pad things to a particular length, but it still requires a mono-space font to look right.